# need to find only subdirs without the top dir

Tags: python, subdirectory

I'm sure there is already an answer but I could not find it because I really do not understand Python code that much. 
I need to find all the subDirs(subDir_path/name) in a directory(C:\01), I found code that I understand but it also prints the Home dir/path (C:\01) and the subDir path/name. It is my first post here. Thank you in advance. 
Here is the code:

```
import os

given_path = 'C:\\01'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(given_path):
    print ("This is path to:  " + path)
    for f in files:
        print ("These are files:"       +f)
    for d in dirs:
        print("These are Directories:"   + d)
```

Comment: so `given_path` + `d` gives you the sub directory path... what is the problem?

Comment: it also printed the path to the 'C:\\01' but I need only the subdirectories without the top directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
dirs = list(map(lambda item: str(item), filter(lambda item: item.is_dir(), Path("c:\\01").rglob("*"))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it but it complains about this part of the code" lamba item"